# Posting user credentials in SAML to a service provider

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have been tasked to implement a SSO process for one our internet sites.  I have been reading as much as I can to fully understand SSO and SAML so here goes:

I need to forward to a 3rd party's Service Provider (SP-3rd_party) the credentials a user used to login to our site (SP1).  Then SP-3rd_party will authenticate those credentials against their own Identity Provider.  Then that 3rd party IdP will redirect back to our service with either success or failure.

Our sites are all written in .NET 4.5.  It seems that we as SP1 should just authenticate against their IdP and not go thru their Service Provider (SP-3rd_party).  Does that make sense?  I feel we are making an additional hop that shouldn't be needed but I am fairly new to all this.  If anyone can provide guidance that would be great.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This use case is commonly referred to as Service Provider Initiated SSO (SP-Init SSO) in SAML 2.0 and is fairly common. You can find a number of resources that outline the flow a little more succinctly -

- http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF70/SP-Initiated+SSO--Redirect-POST#SP-InitiatedSSO--Redirect-POST-1070862
- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation
- Also, see Section 4.1.2 of the SAML 2.0 Tech Overview document - https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/11511/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-draft-03.pdf

HTH -
Ian

Comment: Thank you for the information, Ian.  I will check out those links you provided.